# How to mount more than /home?

Tags: linux, automount, nis, autofs

I have the following in my `/etc/auto.master`

```
/project   yp auto.project   -soft,intr,nosuid
/home      yp auto.home      -soft,intr,nosuid
/nobackup  yp auto.nobackup  -soft,intr,nosuid
```

When a user logs in, his home directory is mounted using NIS.

What I would like, is that the users `/project` and `/nobackup` are also mounted when he logs in.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Should be done with the mount module of PAM (pam_mount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the automounter, is basically to only mount things when needed.  If the maps are correct all the user would have to do is to cd to the area and it will automatically mount.  Once not needed (no users needing the mount after a specified period of time), it will unmount the disk.

The same would happen for the /home area as well if the login shell user cd's to somewhere else other than his home directory.  For you see, the /home directory is mounted due to having to cd to the specified home directory as part of the login.

I'm curious about why you would want what you specified?

If you want it to temporarily mount, you could cd to the necessary directories in the profiles but again without use, they will timeout and become unmounted.

Can you shed more light on your project and objectives?

Comment: Ahh. So they only show up when I `cd` into them. Then it works =)